# MD5 HMAC With OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, md5, hmac

I was trying to generate MD5 HMAC with OpenSSL & most of the code is borrowed.  The hmac being generate is incorrect:

```
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
  unsigned char* key = (unsigned char*) "2012121220121212201212122012121220121212201212122012121220121212";
  unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) "johndoejohndoejohndoejohndoejohndoejohndoejohndoejohndoejohndoejohndoejohndoejohndoe";
  unsigned char* expected = (unsigned char*) "abcd1d87dca34f334786307d0da4fcbd";
  unsigned char* result;
  // unsigned int result_len = 16;
  unsigned int result_len = 16;
  int i;
  static char res_hexstring[32];

  // result = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, 4, data, 28, NULL, NULL);
  result = HMAC(EVP_md5(), key, 32, data, 28, NULL, NULL);
  for (i = 0; i < result_len; i++) {
    sprintf(&(res_hexstring[i * 2]), "%02x", result[i]);
  }

  if (strcmp((char*) res_hexstring, (char*) expected) == 0) {
    printf("Test ok, result length %d\n", result_len);
  } else {
    printf("Got %s instead of %s\n", res_hexstring, expected);
  }
}
```

The hash being produced is incorrect. I would appreciate some feedback or someone pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8):

The third and fifth parameters to HMAC are just wrong. You have to pass the length of the key and the length of data. In your example, this is respectively 64 and 84, not 32 and 28.

So :

```
-    result = HMAC(EVP_md5(), key, 32, data, 28, NULL, NULL);                                                                                                                                                                         
+    result = HMAC(EVP_md5(), key, 64, data, 84, NULL, NULL);
```

With this modification, it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the all-in-one OpenSSL HMAC command tidier, if you write:

`result = HMAC(EVP_md5(), key, sizeof(key)-1, data, sizeof(data)-1, NULL, NULL);`

Because `key` and `data` are initialized with string literals, the last char of both is `\0`. This termination character should not be hashed. We skip this character by specifing the size of the array minus the last char.

You can get other Test Vectors for HMAC-MD5 from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2202.

Comment: it should be `sizeof(key) - 1` and `sizeof(data) - 1` if `key` and `data` are initialized with string literals. Reason: char arrays initialized with a string literal such as `"johndoe"` are appended with the `\0` character. So the corresponding char array actually has the character sequence `johndoe\0`. Usually the `\0` should not be hashed in, because this is a C/C++ specific behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
result = HMAC(EVP_md5(), key, strlen(key), data, strlen(data), NULL, NULL);
```

Instead of

```
result = HMAC(EVP_md5(), key, 32, data, 28, NULL, NULL);
```

It generally work for any **data** & **key**

Comment: If you have this anywhere in your code, it's wrong and you probably got other things wrong. A key is binary data, it may have null bytes. Calling `strlen` on a key is nonsense. The data may happen to be text, or it may not, so calling `strlen` may or may not be right.