# What does this C code snippet mean?

Tags: c, hash

I've come across this piece of code  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555962/md5-hmac-with-openssl).

```
result = HMAC(EVP_md5(), key, 32, data, 28, NULL, NULL);
  for (i = 0; i < result_len; i++) {
    sprintf(&(res_hexstring[i * 2]), "%02x", result[i]);
  }
```

what does the loop do? In particular what does `&(res_hexstring[i * 2])` mean? Can't you just iterate through result as an array? Why is it an integer?

Comment: octets as hex string chars are represented as `00` through `FF`. You could do this one nibble at a time, but whats the point in doing so, *considerably* more work for no gain ? You can assume the `res_hexstring` is used somewhere besides dumping to the console, otherwise yes, the `sprintf` is pointless and it could be done with `printf`.

Comment: and why can't you just use printf?

Answer (score 0):

It converts the hash result to a string:

e.g., from:

```
char result[2] = {0xa1, 0xb2};
```

to

```
char res_hexstring[4 + 1] = {'a', '1', 'b', '2', '\0'}
```

The expression `i * 2` appears in `&res_hexstring[i * 2]` because the byte `0xa1` needs two characters (`'a'`  and `'1'`) to be represented in a string.

The advantage of having a string is it can be then easily displayed:

```
printf("%s\n", res_hexstring);  // display the hash result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < result_len; i++) {
    sprintf(&(res_hexstring[i * 2]), "%02x", result[i]);
}
```

`sprintf` prints the result from the binary array `result` 1 byte <=> 2 nibbles / hexadecimal digits at a time into the buffer `res_hexstring`.

Which is the reason the left index goes 2 byte for each 1 byte the second is moved.

Of course, not using `sprintf` would be much faster, but it would also need a bit more code.
(Which might result in a bigger or smaller binary, but that must be measured if of interest.)

```
inline char to16digit(int x) { return x<10 ? '0'+x : 'A'-10+x; }
for (i = 0; i < result_len; i++) {
    res_hexstring[i*2]   = to16digit(result[i]>>4);
    res_hexstring[i*2+1] = to16digit(result[i]&15);
}
res_hexstring[2*result_len] = 0;
```

There are various reasons you might want it in a human-readable form, serializing, printing and logging prominent among them. (And `printf` does not have a format to print such big numbers in hexadecimal notation.)

Comment: So what is the form of  'result'? It is defined as unsigned char* result; is it  a char or an array of hexadecimal values? What does the hash function return?

Comment: @w774: `result` is a binary blob of length `result_len`.